# RTF - Show Alternative Text?

Tags: c#, rtf, text-formatting

I want to display alternative text instead of a paragraph. This question is **still unresolved**. It's about RTF like when I hide text via `\v hidden\v0 not hidden`.

MS Visual Studio (at least 2010) can hide code sections with regions:

```
#region test
private static void myMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello world");
}
#endregion
```

So when you fold you see only **`test`**.

I want to do the same with RTF. Say I take a paragraph, hide it and show alternative text **`test`** instead of the paragraph. And when the user copies the **`test`** he copies the hidden paragraph. How can I do that ?

*(I'm working with RichTextBox in C#)*

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, you want the text to be shown but not be able to copy it?